# Use images to choose templates

Tags: html, css, wordpress

The idea is to create a user friendly way to choose your template in Wordpress so the user can see what the template will look like as they choose it. Instead of having text in a dropwdown list I would like to have images to choose from.

EDIT : 
**To clarify what I was aiming at:**

It is Admin-end. When you create a page you can choose template's on the right in a dropdown and that's what I would like to change to being images to choose from so the Admin can see what the page is going to look like with that template.

E.g. when using advanced custom fields I can add fields that will be used when choosing a specifik template, but the admin can not see how that page will look when they choose a template. They just get to see the title of the template but I would like to be able to show an image that shows how that template will look.

where do I edit this? is this possible in Wordpress?

Answer (score 0):

**Viewer-end or Admin-end?**

Yes it is possible.

There is already way to change Themes (also called as "Templates") in WordPress, which is only accessible through login credentials. *Pictures are also included.*

**Or**

You can also make buttons that allow users (viewers) without login credentials to change the way how your website looks. You can do this using Javascript by changing current style to other.

```
$('#template').click(function (){
  $('link[href="style.css"]').attr('href','style.css');
});

$('#template1').click(function (){
  $('link[href="style1.css"]').attr('href','style1.css');
});

$('#template2').click(function (){
  $('link[href="style2.css"]').attr('href','style2.css');
});
```

There are really numerous ways how to make it.